# need write permission to network server on Linux and Macintosh

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, permissions, mount

I can read from a remote server using

sudo mount //Bor****ges/imgdisk4 /home/ilan/remoteDisks/biMnt -o user=**,pass=**

There is something similar for the Mac, which also can't write, but I want to concentrate on Linux for the moment. I thought perhaps the server itself isn't giving me write permission, so I used a Windows machine. Under Windows I have no problems writing, so the server itself isn't blocking me.

In an answer in superuser I found this

sudo mount -o umask=0,uid=nobody,gid=nobody /dev/something /mnt/somewhere

I tried adding -o umask=0,user=**,pass=**, but it complained that the syntax was incorrect. I went to the man page for mount and found the correct syntax was -w, which is the default. If it is the default I should have always been able to write. In any case, I removed umask=0 and added -w. The result, not surprisingly, was that I still can't write to the network drive.

Can anyone tell me where the problem lies and what I need to do to solve it?

Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: With my original command, a mount command with no arguments gives://Bor*ges/imgdisk4 on /home/ilan/remoteDisks/biMnt type cifs (rw). According to this I should have read write permission, but I don't.

Comment: Try setting uid and gid to the user / group ID that you want to grant access. Additionally, for Samba mounts it might be better to use smbmount instead of directly calling mount

Comment: It is telling me I have a syntax error. I tried umask=000 but that didn't help. I need to specify my user name and pw to get onto the server. Maybe that doesn't work with umask=000? The error is:mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Comment: I tried smbmount long ago. I no longer remember what the problem was, but eventually I went to mount. The strange thing is that mount with no arguments says I have rw permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the answer I found in the hopes that it might help somebody else.

My machine is Ubuntu 13.10 and I have Windows XP running in a virtual box. From XP I could write to the server so that I knew the server itself had no objections.

Going into the man mount.cifs I found there was an option to turn off the client side permissions checking. It was clearly stated that the server itself could still veto the write, but from XP I knew that the server would not object. I specifically requested the rw option, which may not be necessary since it is the default. The crucial part was the noperm option. The command which works is:

sudo mount //Bor*ges/imgdisk4 /home/ilan/remoteDisks/biMnt -o rw,noperm,user=,pass=

After getting Linux up and running, I also managed to the Mac going as well. The Mac was easier in that it only involved setting the rw flag.

Ilan